# Xpath selector difference: pros and cons

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have two xpath selectors that find exactly the same element, but I wonder which one is better from code, speed of execution, readability points of view etc.

**First Xpath :**

```
//*[@id="some_id"]/table/tbody/tr[td[contains(., "Stuff_01")]]//ancestor-or-self::td/input[@value="Stuff_02"]
```

**Second Xpath:**

```
//tr[td[@title="Stuff_01"]]//ancestor-or-self::td/input[@value="Stuff_02"]
```

The argument for example is that if the code of the page will be changed and for example some `"tbody"` will be moved that the first one won't work, is it true ?
So any way which variant of the code is better and why ?

I would appreciate an elaborate answer, because this is crucial to the workflow.

Comment: maybe the answers to this my old question will be helpful! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092985/find-elements-by-data-attributes

Comment: Partly it does, thx, but not all of it...

Comment: I will add it as an answer to help other users too

Comment: **1** If this is *crucial* as you say, you should take the time to include a reduced example of the targeted HTML and a description of exactly what you're trying to select, because it is possible that neither XPath is ideal.   **2** Performance is unlikely to matter; measure first.  **3** ...especially if you use an `@id` or other anchor point to hone in on a reduced subtree before further restraining the selection space.

Comment: @kjhughes could you explain your 3rd point ?

Comment: If there's only one `elem` with `id` of `1234` in the document, by using `//elem[@id="1234"]/rest-of-xpath`, you've eliminated the rest of the document as a performance/readability/robustness concern.  As long as the subtree below `elem` is relatively tame (and it usually will be), you'll be fine regarding those concerns.    Also, yes, `table//td` is a fine way to cover whether `tbody` is present or not.

Comment: Please show a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sample of your HTML document. Otherwise, nobody can tell you more than @kjhughes already did. The usefulness of XPath expressions depends highly on the document you apply them to. (And to emphasize this again, we also need to know _what you are looking for_.)

Comment: @kjhughes ok, your answer did if for me, post it as an Answer and i will accepts, thanks!

Comment: @Mathias Müller i just needed basic rules for which type of code to use preferably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that neither XPath is ideal.  Seeing the targeted HTML and a description of the selection goal would be needed to decide or to offer another alternative.

Also, as with all performance matters, measure first.

That said, performance is unlikely to matter, especially if you use an `@id` or other anchor point to hone in on a reduced subtree before further restraining the selection space.

For example, if there's only one `elem` with `id` of `1234` in the document, by using `//elem[@id="1234"]/rest-of-xpath`, you've eliminated the rest of the document as a performance/readability/robustness concern. As long as the subtree below `elem` is relatively tame (and it usually will be), you'll be fine regarding those concerns.

Also, yes, `table//td` is a fine way to abstract over whether `tbody` is present or not.