# Capybara find anchor element by data attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

With [capybara](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara) I am trying to find an anchor element by its data attribute so that I can click it.  This anchor element is dynamic so the easiest way for me to grab it is by its data attribute.

I did look at the Capybara docs on the [find method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method), and [this similar question's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092985/find-elements-by-data-attributes) was not working out for me.  I am either making a syntax error or I am missing something.

Within my anchor tag here is my data attribute:

```
data-delete-association-field-name=“item[item_orders_attributes][0][_destroy]"
```

So with Capybara I am ultimately trying to find the anchor tag with that data attribute and then click it.  Here is my current implementation which is not working:

```
find(‘a[data-delete-association-field-name=item[item_orders_attributes][0][_destroy]]’).click
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed to specify the css selector for the data attribute.

[This question shows the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css) for a css selector by data attribute.  I then just had to apply that to the capybara `find` method like so:

```
find(‘a[data-delete-association-field-name="item[item_orders_attributes][0][_destroy]"]’).click
```